# Generate Word document with updated TOC using Velocity template

Tags: ms-word, velocity, jama, vtl

I am currently working on a Velocity template for exporting data from the JAMA platform.

I am required to follow an specific document format. This format includes a table of contents that currently is correctly created in the document.

The issue is that the table is exported empty, without taking into account the titles that are in the document. This can be easily corrected by manually updating the table but, when exporting a big number of documents is very time consuming.

Is there a way for updating the table automatically when performing the export?

Comment: Probably not, as updating a TOC field (the underlying codes that dynamically manage a Table of Contents) requires the document being open in hte Word application. Also, this is necessary in order to get the correct *page numbers* - a Word document is only paginated in the Word application interface.

Comment: I see. As a "work-around", could it be possible creating a macro (from the vtl template) that updates the TOC when opening the document?

Comment: I don't know - I've never used that environment. My only non-interop experience is working with the Open XML (SDK) side of things. And I know that's how it works with the TOC for that. One thing that is possible, if you have SharePoint Server on-prem is to use Word Automation Services to open the document, which will up-date the TOC...